# Chrome auto-fills password but not username on bank website

Tags: google-chrome, username, auto-form-fill

On my bank's website, [direct.com](https://www.direct.com), Chrome will auto-fill the password after I enter the username, but it doesn't auto-fill the username by itself.

I read in [Chrome auto-fill username/passwords is inconsistant](https://superuser.com/questions/86282/chrome-auto-fill-username-passwords-is-inconsistant) that this can happen if there are multiple usernames saved. I checked the Chrome Password Manager, and this isn't the case. Also, in my experience, when there are multiple usernames, clicking on the username field will display a menu of the remembered usernames. But that doesn't happen here.

The HTML for the username field is:

```
<input id="userid" maxlength="256" name="userid" type="text" class="formTextHeader placeholder" placeholder="USERNAME" value="" aria-label="User Name">
```

Is it because the name is `userid` rather than something more standard like `username`?

The form has `autocomplete="off"` set, but apparently Chrome ignores that because it's filling in the password.

It's been like this for years, through multiple MacOS and Chrome upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

## General solution

There is a cross-browser, cross-platform solution to some input-form problems that might help you as well. No addons required, but it takes 3 minutes and some html knowledge:

#### Adding a temporary fake form

Specific instructions here are for Chrome and Firefox (on Linux), but it should be extremely similar for other browsers and other platforms (for macOS replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>).

1. Right click the input field (username) and select <kbd>Inspect</kbd> or <kbd>Inspect element</kbd>.
2. Remember or write down the value of `name` or `id` of that field. Repeat these steps also for the password input field.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to select any element to replace it with a fake input field.
4. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit that element's source.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole element's source.
6. Paste the following instead of the element's source:

```
<form method=post>
  <input name=IDENTIFIER>
  <input type=password name=PASSWORD>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

7. Replace `IDENTIFIER` and `PASSWORD` with the ones you got from step 2.
8. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply your changes. You can now close the developer menu.
9. Type your username and password into the 2 new input fields that appeared.
10. Click <kbd>Submit</kbd>. You might get an error or nothing visible might happen.
11. Now your browser should offer to save the credentials in a popup or maybe you need to click a key shaped button in the corner of the address bar to get that popup.

---

Original source with extra background [here](https://superuser.com/a/1084364/290915).
Almost same answer to a different question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/371800/348772).

Comment: The username is already saved in the Chrome password manager. The problem is just that it doesn't fill that field in automatically. I have to type the password by hand, then it auto-fills the password.

Comment: Ah yeah. Sorry for not clarifying. I suspected that there is a slight possibility that this still helps you. By giving the browser the id/name of the username input field. But this is a bit of a long shot. I don't really expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome password were always problematic. I suggest you would do better to use
a third-party password manager. This can help centralize your password and
form-fields repository across all devices and all browsers.

My preferred is [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/),
and you will find it also as a
[Chrome add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass-free-password-ma/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd).
You could in addition install the desktop version of LastPass on your computers
and the LastPass app on your smartphone.

Comment: I'm not going to switch to a new password manager just to resolve a really minor glitch in one one website.

Answer (score 0):

## Specific solution:

You can always change the existing html with a userscript. To activate userscripts you need an addon like GreaseMonkey or Tampermonkey.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix direct.com login issue
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Find all elements with the autocomplete attribute (at the login page) and change that attribute to "on".
// @author       Carolus
// @match        https://www.direct.com/index.cfm
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var allElements, thisElement;
    allElements = document.evaluate(
        '//*[@autocomplete]',
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
        null
    );
    for (var i = 0; i < allElements.snapshotLength; i++) {
        thisElement = allElements.snapshotItem(i);
        thisElement.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
    }
})();
```

This is my first ever userscript, cobbled together in 30 min, so it is not perfect. But it does enable you to choose the name and password as a dropdown option when you click on the input box and then follow it with another click or a downward arrow press. I couldn't figure out how to make it be filled out when you land on the page. But maybe someone can edit this answer to have an even better user script.

Comment: This kind of works, but the menu with the username doesn't show my actual username. But then when I auto-fill the password, it replaces the username field with the correct name. While playing around with this I discovered that even without the userscript, auto-filling the password does this.